# How to see the API errors on angular jhipster interface

Tags: jhipster

Im starting with jHipster.

I've created a entity with some JPA validators and when i try to save one that does not comply i get 400 bad request (expected). However i do not see any signal of error in the user interface.

I see the request/response and there is no error message at all

I is there no basic error handling?

EDIT:

Ok ... i actually see the error message in the response HTTP ... but nothing in the interface.

```
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException"
message: "Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Void> com.hipsterspike.web.rest.ItemResource.update(com.hipsterspike.domain.Item) throws java.net.URISyntaxException, with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'item' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.item.name,NotNull.name,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [item.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [may not be null]] "
path: "/api/items"
status: 400
timestamp: 1427493286237
```